# Database design schema for a simple community website

Tags: mysql, database, templates, schema

Where can I find a template for a database design schema. I will be using MySQL. It is a simple website where users, managers, admin can login. Also user can pay a subscription fees and one time fees Using credit card or paypal. I am really confuse how to design the database properly without having major issues later on in the project.This is just a pet project so my resource is none. If you guys could help me out that would be much appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use followings for reference purpose, and alter them a bit for your need. If you are looking for full functioning data model explicitly for you, then I think, you may not be able to find it.

1. [Sample Databases](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/SampleDatabases.html), use 5th one, I think it suits best for you.
2. [Mysql sample](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html) just for reference.